# My MathJaX font turned ugly all of a sudden

Tags: support, mathjax, font

This last week while browsing this site my computer has displayed MathJaX really badly. Here is a screenshot from a random question:
[image: Ugly fonted math mode]

Here is a screenshot of the same question from my phone for comparison (slightly blurry on my screen due to scaling):
[image]

To me that looks a lot better. I would normally search elsewhere for the answer, but StackExchange is, as far as I can tell, the only site where this font change has taken place.

I am using Chrome on a Windows 7 machine. Mozilla Firefox has the same problem, while Internet Explorer looks good. Zooming in and out doesn't help. I don't think I've touched any settings lately. Does anyone know what might cause this?

Edit:
After some help from Willie Wong, here is a screenshot with the math renderer changed from HTML-CSS to SVG:
[image]

It looks a lot better, but it seems very boldfaced, like the G, H and brackets really stands out on the page.

Comment: Another user had a similar problem [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16787/latex-formulae-now-look-strange). What is the status of MathJax in Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer?

Comment: @Moronplusplus: I marked that other one as a dupe of this one, to help keep track of the status.

Comment: @Moronplusplus FF has the same problem. IE looks good.

Comment: @Arthur: in each of the three browsers you tested, can you right click on the math expression, go to "Settings --> Math Renderer", and tells us what the renderers used are for each of the browsers. After that, can you try using different renderers and see if they change the situation?

Comment: @WillieWong They were all using HTML-CSS, though in FF and Chrome's case, SVG looks a whole lot better.

Comment: @Arthur: one last question: do you happen to have the STIX fonts installed? (BTW, I probably cannot help you solve the problem. I am just going through the routines so when the real experts arrive all the usual questions are already asked and they can trouble shoot from there.)

Comment: @WillieWong There is no font called STIX installed on my computer, if that's what you mean. I don't know if it might be installed under a different name by default.

Comment: That's fine. If you don't know about it, you probably did not install it. It is not something that usually gets dragged in on Windows.

Comment: While you Mathjax technicians are at it, be advised that a problem that had been cured once before has recurred. Once again, non-Mathjax text which follows Mathjax text encroaches upon it. In answer to the question, What am I working with(?), here goes: Samsung Galaxy S5, Android platform, service provided by Verizon. Good hunting!

Comment: What does MathJax report as font being used when you open the about popup in the MathJax menu?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger It says it uses woff or otf fonts.

Comment: Ah, too bad. I was hoping it'd say image fonts (indicating that something is blocking the webfonts). But woff/otf is the right type. What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Hey, are there those who still have this bug? I know the answer to this naughty question, since I have published the same report.